# Grouping on virtual (predefined) column in linq

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, linq-to-entities, grouping

I am trying to write a linq query for one of my dashboard which retrieves data based on some conditions. I want to display records count based on the different status available in my table.

Following is the SQL query in which I am trying to convert into Linq.

```
select count(id) cnt, 'Available' label from table where date = sysdate
```

Above query is returning below result in DB IDE. This is the result I want with linq

```
cnt    label
0      Available
```

I've tried with following linq query but it is returning 0 count and hence result is not being retrieved.

```
var data = (from a in context
where a.date = System.DateTime.Now
group a in a.id into g
select new {
cnt = g.Count(),
label = 'Available'
}).ToList();
```

How do I achieve above mentioned result in linq. Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks

**-------------EDIT----------------**
**Updated LINQ query**

```
var data = (from a in context.TableA
where a.id = uniqueID
group a in a.id into g
select new {
cnt = g.Count(),
label = 'Available'
}).Concat(from a in context.TableB
where a.id = uniqueID
group a in a.id into g
select new {
cnt = g.Count(),
label = 'WIP'
}).ToList();
```

Comment: You don't have a where clause on your SQL query, but then do in your Linq, and I doubt your tables date column is the same as the current DateTime.Now (I can guarantee it isn't). Remove the 'where' from your linq.

Comment: Do you want to count the number of elements in data that have a specific id, or to count the number of unique id's within data?

Comment: @Dispersia - I have updated the SQL query. Please refer updated one. Still it returns 1 row in DB IDE but not with linq. FYI, I need this where condition for filtering the result. Thanks

Comment: @AlexeiBarnes - I need count the number of element in the data that belongs to a specific ID. If you see I put in the linq. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To count the number of elements matching a predicate in a linq query simply use the `where` clause:

```
var results =
    from a in context
    where a.date.Date == DateTime.Now.Date
       && a.id == someIdHere
    select a;

var data = new {
    count = results.Count(),
    label = "Available"
};
```

Or, in extension method syntax (which I prefer):

```
var results = context.Where(a => a.date.Date == DateTime.Now.Date && a.id == someIdHere);

var data = new {
    count = results.Count(),
    label = "Available"
};
```

Also be careful when comparing a `DateTime` object with regards to what results you desire; comparing `DateTime.Now` to a date will likley return false since it will compare the time code as well, use the `DateTime.Date` property to obtain only the date from the object for the purposes of comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Looking at the LINQ and lambda expression, It should work as expected but can't we get this out put in single query. Actually, I have used 'Concat' extension method in linq to get my result based on different label and hence I am trying a single linq which gives the count of record based on different labels.

Comment: It may be possible, but I would avoid over complicating things by forcing everything into a single query; the desire to put everything into large statements just leads to unmaintainable code in my experience. Please remember to mark this as an answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Yes I understand it may be a complicated linq but instead of having multiple DB trips, I would suggest to have a single query which retrieves entire data based on the suggestion and hence having this approach. I would not agree with "unmaintainable code" if we are putting the aggregation logic with LINQ. It depends on the way of writing linq and logic that you are trying to manage. See i have updated my question with "Concat" statement. Thanks

Comment: This has turned into multiple problems, please do not edit your question to contain new questions, simply open a new question. For now; if you want to combine collections then I would recommend that you look up the `Join` extension method if you need a pivot, and start by concatenating or joining your collections and then performing your query on the result of that.